# How to set bottom view always below to its top view even the top view 's height is bigger/smaller than screen?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

[[I have 3 layouts inside relative layout like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Q1B.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Q1B.png)

**My target is to make layout 3 always below layout 2 which is a Recycler view.**

*It is perfectly working when the list item size is small, but when it grows, Layout 3 is being pushed out of the screen*

**I want to adjust layout 3 always below layout 2 even thought layout 2's height increases or decreases. if it grown more than the screen size, just place layout3 at the bottom and layout 2 above the layout 3.**

1. Layout 1 is heading.
2. Layout 2 is Recycler view.
3. Layout 3 is summary.

I tried parentBottom true for layout 3, it works when the list item is full of screen, but it remains on bottom if list item is lesser, (eg, 4, 5 items).

**Please help me.**

**My xml is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bill_heading_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            style="@style/billing_heading"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:text="@string/sn" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/billing_heading"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:text="@string/item_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rateTv"
            style="@style/billing_heading"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:text="@string/rates" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/billing_heading"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/qty" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/billing_heading"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:text="@string/total_value" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/billing_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bill_heading_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/billing_recycler"
        android:id="@+id/summary_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/billing_border"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_total_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="2.8"
                android:gravity="end|center"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sub_total" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subQtyTv"
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/qty" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subTotalTv"
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight=".9"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:text="@string/total_value" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/discount_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="2.8"
                android:gravity="end|center"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:text="@string/discount" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/discountTv"
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight=".9"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:text="@string/total_value" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scheme_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="2.8"
                android:gravity="end|center"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:text="@string/scheme" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/schemeTv"
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight=".9"
                android:text="@string/total_value"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/grand_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="2.8"
                android:gravity="end|center"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:text="@string/grand_total" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grandTotalTv"
                style="@style/billing_summary"
                android:layout_weight=".9"
                android:text="@string/total_value"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHETn.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHETn.png)

[[Rusult 2: when `parentBottom=ture`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNp7z.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNp7z.png)

**I tried second approach by using Constraint Layout as a parent layout as below**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:spanCount="29" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/make_report"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerView" />
```

[[And I got the result as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91T6Z.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91T6Z.png)

*Button at the very bottom position is pushed out. I tried* `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` as per answered suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067590/akanshi-srivastava, it worked for list item having more span counting. when the list count comes to 4 or 5, there is gap between list item and button as this [[gap between list and button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Xgf.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Xgf.png), which I don't to have in this layout. I want that, if the list count is lesser, want button to attach just below list like this [[button just below list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtX51.png)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtX51.png) and when list grows more than screen size, I want button just attach at the bottom and list until above the button and start its scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ConstrainLayout` and you can set the bottom view's

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

This way, no matter what you add to the screen and whatever is it's width/height, this view will always be at the bottom.
On top of that, I see you have a lot of nested `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`.
`ConstraintLayout` will help you flatten the layout hierarchy. You can read the official documentation to understand the benefits of `ConstraintLayout` and how to use it.

Comment: I tried it, but the bottom view always remained at bottom position.
But I want that, if the list item is less count (let's say 4 or 5), the bottom layout should attach just below the list item [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Q1B.png). But if list item is big (let's say 30, 50) [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHETn.png) then the bottom layout should attach at the bottom and list view just above the bottom view and start scrolling. I tried making list height to match constraint (0dp) and bottom to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`, it works as only for big list count.